Getting error when using memory with chain: TypeError: Object of type Member is not serializable
I am getting this error: TypeError: Object of type Member is not serializable when trying to have memory with a chain.
My program is a discord bot that answers with AI on_message, The discord part completely works and I have removed some functions in the shown code.
This works without the memory.
class WhiteTiger(discord.Client):
    def __init__(self, intents):
        super().__init__(intents=intents)
        self.target_channel = None
        self.llm = ChatOllama(
            model="llama3.2",
            temperature=0,
        )
        self.prompt = ChatPromptTemplate.from_messages(
            [
                (
                    "system",
                    "<context>",
                ),
                MessagesPlaceholder(variable_name="messages"),
            ]
        )
        self.chain = self.prompt | self.llm

        self.init_memory()

    def init_memory(self):
        workflow = StateGraph(state_schema=DiscordMessagesState)

        def call_model(state: DiscordMessagesState):
            response = self.chain.invoke(state)
            return {"messages": [response]}

        workflow.add_edge(START, "model")
        workflow.add_node("model", call_model)

        self.memory = MemorySaver()
        self.app = workflow.compile(checkpointer=self.memory)
        self.config = {"configurable": {"thread_id": "abc1234"}}


    async def on_message(self, message):
        if (
            self.target_channel
            and message.channel.id == self.target_channel.id
            and message.author.id != self.user.id
        ):
            print(f"Message from {message.author}: {message.content}")

            print(f"{message.author}: {message.content}")

            reply = self.app.invoke(
                {
                    "messages": [HumanMessage(f"{message.author}: {message.content}")],
                    "author": message.author,
                },
                self.config
            )

            await message.reply(
                reply["messages"][-1].pretty_print(), mention_author=True
            )

Full traceback: 
Thanks in advance!

This error occurs because you are passing a Member object to a function which later tries to convert it to JSON and fails.
To fix that, you need to pass a member's name, ID, or other string or int which is serializable. It seems name is the thing you are looking for:
reply = self.app.invoke(
    {
        "messages": [HumanMessage(f"{message.author}: {message.content}")],
        "author": message.author.name,
    },
    self.config
)


Thanks! Before seeing this i fixed the error with str(message.author), but this is cleaner.
